# Facebook Javascript Login Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, authentication

I want to know if the facebook login button for javascript can invoke any other function by assigning it a click event handler. According to my knowledge this button automatically calls `FB.LOGIN` when clicked. Is there a way to make this button respond to some special type of action? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some specific actions during to the **login** event, you can simply subscribe to this event by attaching an handler with it.

You can do this by using [FB.Event.subcribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). It is basically used to attache an handler to an event and invoke your callback when the event fires.

Comment: Hi, I use the `auth.authResponseChange` change event and i checked for two instances with the callback 'response',  `response.status === 'connected'` , `response.status === 'not_authorized'` . I placed my function within the not_authorized code block like `if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      myFunction();}` Now the problem is that my function executes before the button is clicked. Is there a way to fix this. Thanks

Comment: It should work like that. Are you initializing the response variable every time before calling FB.Event.subscribe?

Comment: Here's what i got. What is wrong with this. My function keeps running before the button is clicked. `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      myFunction();
    } else {
    myFunction();
    }`

Comment: That's because you are calling the `myFunction()` in the else part. (Sorry for the late reply, I've been very busy).